# Cakephp does not work in IIS?

Tags: cakephp, iis, cakephp-3.0, iis-10

I've a issue with Cakephp Version 3.2 on IIS. But, Cakephp Version 2.2 is working well in the same setup environment. Not sure why?

Here's my `web.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Exclude direct access to webroot/*"
                  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^webroot/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)"
                  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(img|css|files|js|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}{R:2}"
                      appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php"
                  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"
                      appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above content was copied from the [Official Cakephp forum](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#iis7-windows-hosts).

Whatever we type in URL, I get the below response

[image]

**Note** :

I tried all the related links in SO & I posted this after trying all the provided solutions but none of them worked.

More Information :

IIS Ver - 10
Cakephp - 3.2

I repeat again, Cakephp 2.2 works well.

Comment: You should check the error logs and post the relevant messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my own question on how i solved the problem. The problem is not with web.config but the real problem is in .gitignore.

By Default it adds `vendor` directory to .gitignore. Since it doesn't added to git, those errors were occurred.